# How to post data from user control - asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Currently i am working on project in which login user control is there in master page. earlier i had seperate login.aspx page and was able to call login method of home controller (with acceptverb = post). now we have changed the idea, want to place login control on master page (home page).

Now when i click on login button of login control - it calls login method of controller class with acceptver = get. how can i call login method with acceptverb = post?

Comment: did you specify the Action attribute on the button?

Answer (score 0):

Is the button within a form?  It has to be within a form to do a post...

Answer (score 0):

As Brian said, you should put your form login controls in a form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home")) { %>
 ...your form & submit here
<% } %>
```